# UEFI Boot Device Detection Issue on Debian and Dell Precision 5530 - Need Expert Advice and Insight

Tags: debian, uefi

I encountered a strange problem with UEFI on my Dell Precision 5530 with Debian 12 on an internal NVME SSD and would appreciate any expert insights to help me understand what happened.

Initially, I had Debian 12 running successfully on my laptop. I wanted to install Windows 11 on an external Thunderbolt drive, so I went into the Dell BIOS menu and unchecked the NVMe drive in the storage options to minimize the risk of the Windows installation overwriting the bootloader on my Debian drive.

I then booted from a Windows 11 installation USB stick, but encountered an error related to drivers and storage. I decided to abandon the installation for the time being and rebooted the system, going back into the BIOS and re-enabling the NVME SSD.

However, upon rebooting, the system complained that there was no valid boot device. I checked the list of UEFI boot devices in the BIOS, but none were listed. I then booted from a Debian Live USB stick and confirmed that the NVMe drive was visible with `lsblk`. The BIOS could see the storage, but it didn't recognize it as a boot device.

I tried adjusting various BIOS settings to get the system to recognize the drive, but nothing worked. Eventually, I reset the BIOS to factory defaults, but the "no valid boot device" error persisted. In the end, I reinstalled Debian 12, and the BIOS recognized the NVMe SSD as a valid boot device again.

I'm curious about what caused my original SSD to be undetected as a valid UEFI boot device by the BIOS, and why reinstalling the OS fixed the issue. I'm confident that the SSD wasn't touched during the process since I had removed it from the BIOS. Was I wrong to disable the device in the BIOS which removed it from the UEFI ROM on the motherboard? If it did, is that expected behavior? Any expert advice would be greatly appreciated. I'm really looking to understand what possibly happened.

Should I have physically removed the M.2 storage instead of disabling it?

Comment: When UEFI does not see a drive, it changes the UEFI setting. You can reinstall grub to update it again, or use efibootmgr to create new entry. Can you boot the fallback entry. Most systems have a UEFI fallback drive boot entry, like booting the external drive that used /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. Windows does not install to external drives, not sure if it would consider a Thunderbolt drive as internal? See `man efibootmgr` for examples of using it. I know the command for Ubuntu but not Debian, although it should be similar.

Comment: Thanks for that info. This certainly seems the case. You may be right about windows on thunderbolt. I didn’t see any backup uefi entry so maybe this Dell does not have that.